# Are there any pre-written component-like Silverlight web widgets like there are for Flash?

Tags: flash, silverlight, components

Are there any pre-written component-like Silverlight web widgets like there are for Flash?

Flash examples:
[XSPF Web Music Player](http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/)
[WordPress Audio Player](http://wpaudioplayer.com/)
[FLAMPlayer](http://www.flamplayer.com/flamplayer_demo/pages/demo.html)
[Aflax](http://www.aflax.org/demos.htm)

Clarification: I don't mean controls to use in your IDE to write something custom.
See [ALTNET Podcast](http://altnetpodcast.com/)
I think they use the WordPress Audio Player.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of controls, [silverlight.net](http://silverlight.net) is a good place to start.  Infragistics and Telerik are making prebuilt controls for Silverlight, other third parties are coming on board as well.  I notice most of your examples are audio and video players- I don't think there are any separate controls for that, audio and video playing is baked directly in.
Google "silverlight controls" and you should have plenty to try out.

Comment: I meant components really. Things you just embed on a page and they give you more capabilities without writing anything custom. Not that I'm against writing anything, but I see this evolution on the Flash-side as important. Especially a project like Aflax, although I'm unsure of its current status.

Answer (score 1):

There sure are.

I have used some from Component One
http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioSilverlight/

Other companies like Telerik have some good ones too:
http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you could also check out project blacklight

Open source

http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/